# How to display variable value in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  test = path
  if $('#spot-index-sortable').length > 0

    $('#spot-index-sortable').sortable(

      axis: 'y'
      items: '.item'
      cursor: 'move'

      sort: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow')
      stop: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow')
        # highlight the row on drop to indicate an update
        ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
      update: (e, ui) ->
        item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
        console.log(item_id)
        position = ui.item.index() # this will not work with paginated items, as the index is zero on every page
        $.ajax(
          type: 'POST',
          url: test+'admin/spot_categories/update_row_order',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { category: {category_id: item_id, row_order_position: position } }
        )
    )
```

The variable test will have a value from javascript then I want to concatenate the test variable value above at the $.ajax(url:test). how to do this

Comment: What is `path`?  Where did that get defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: note the double quotes

```
url: "#{test}/admin/spot_categories/update_row_order",
```

Comment: Which is literally no different than what he *did* do.  The real question is... where did the `path` value come from?

Comment: How do you figure? His question is pretty declarative to me "How do I display a variable"... he shows a string. TO me, that screams interpolation. Coffeescript compiles to js, which you know. His code is not doing that, he is doing traditional js concat... he asked "how do you do it in coffeescript", not "my path is undefined"... etc.. or "I am getting 'this' error and I don't know what it is..".

Comment: i assume he means that test is declared outside the scope of this function so maybe `window.test`? Hard to know with 'a value from javascript' as a description.

Comment: What I'm saying is that in coffeescript:  `test + "/admin/stuff"` is identical, and compiles to the exact same javascript, as:  `"#{test}/admin/stuff"`